# Selenium Problem: New searches keep grabbing the element from an old search

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I am running a loop that performs a search and grabs an element. The element on each search page appears to have the same CSS selector. However, it always prints the element associated with one search, the search I first began testing the script with. Not sure if this a CSS selector issue? Or a cookie issue perhaps?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions import presence_of_element_located

EXE_PATH = r'C:\\geckodriver.exe'

tickers = ["bitcoin", "ethereum", "litecoin"]

for t in tickers:

    with webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = EXE_PATH) as driver:
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
        driver.get("https://coingecko.com/en")
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".px-2").send_keys(t + Keys.RETURN)
        first_result = wait.until(presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.text-3xl > span:nth-child(1)")))
        price = first_result.get_attribute("innerHTML")
        print(price)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the root cause of that issue my friend. The thing is that when you are sending the ticker in search field, it is taking some time to load the options as search field is an auto suggestive dropdown. But as per your script as soon as you are sending the ticker to the search field, you are hitting the enter button and the thing which is happening in the background is it is selecting bitcoin because if you will see in the trending bitcoin is at rank 1 and because of the lack of delay in between sending the ticker and hitting the enter, it is selecting bitcoin by default. I have modified a script you can view it below. If you don't want to use sleep then add web driver wait and wait for the desired option to be displayed in the search field drop down. Hope so that helps you. Please mark it is as accepted if you are happy with my answer.

tickers = ["bitcoin", "ethereum", "litecoin"]

for t in tickers:

```
with webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = EXE_PATH) as driver:
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    driver.get("https://coingecko.com/en")
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".px-2").send_keys(t)
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".px-2").send_keys(Keys.RETURN);
    first_result = wait.until(presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.text-3xl > span:nth-child(1)")))
    price = first_result.get_attribute("innerHTML")
    print(pric
```